# Adding Border to the image using FFmpeg

Tags: image, ffmpeg, border

I wish to add a border to the single strip of images, using FFMPEG.

I have been trying to search this thing on google, I tried this command ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "draw box= : x=50 : y=10 : w=104 : h=80 : color=white" output.jpg, I am unable to increase the border size as well as my desired color,Its work only black border.how can I increase the border and change the color to the single strip of images. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please do no crosspost the same question on multiple [se] sites: [Adding Border to the image using FFmpeg](http://superuser.com/q/682963/110524).

Comment: For anyone that landed on this question, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48485799/ffmpeg-extend-not-resize-video-size-by-adding-box-or-border) SO answer working for me. (answer is not only for videos)

Answer (score 1):

Adding border to an existing image is similar to add water mark image to some image,

Here is the ffmpeg command to add border to your image

```
ffmpeg -i image1.jpeg -vf "movie=border_1.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]" one.jpg
```

**Note**

=> Width & height of image1.jpeg and border1.png file should be same only

=> Both files are same directory

=> In border_1.png, except border , all other area is transparent

Here is the similar article that I referred to add water mark to video

http://www.idude.net/index.php/how-to-watermark-a-video-using-ffmpeg/

Inacase if you want to add border to your video then there is a minor change in above command

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -vf "movie=border_1.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]" outputvideo.mp4
```

Now again , keep in mind widht & height of border image and video are same only.

ffmpeg version I am using is **ffmpeg version N-61041-g52a2138**