# Adding border to image like google photo scan app in android

Tags: java, android, image, watermark

Is it possible to add border to a image without showing the image to the user in android.
Like google photo scan app..[Here a border is added to image with photoscan logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoNdm.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at Outlined card here. https://material.io/develop/android/components/cards/

Comment: I want to save the image to storage in background, i wont show it to user

Comment: You can try with ffmpeg, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325980/adding-border-to-the-image-using-ffmpeg, https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-January/013139.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Designed a custom layout with a image view
- Inflated it to a view object
- Set the my image to that image view in layout
- Drawn the view to a bitmap and saved it

Code for inflating and drawing

```
    public Bitmap drawToBitmap(Context context, final int layoutResId,
                           final int width, final int height, String imageDescription) {
    final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    final LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(layoutResId, null);
    ImageView img = layout.findViewById(R.id.imgAnalysedBitmap);
    img.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    layout.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    layout.layout(0, 0, layout.getMeasuredWidth(), layout.getMeasuredHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, new Paint());
    return bmp;
}
```

Usage:

```
final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        Bitmap bmap = drawToBitmap(this, R.layout.layout_watermark, metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, imageDescription);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this this library

`implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'`

in Xml File

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.BubbleImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/neo"
    app:siArrowPosition="right"
    app:siSquare="true"/>
```

Comment: I don't want to show to image to the user, I have to add border to image and save it to storage in background, Image will be not be shown to user